# Round the Relative Layout from bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using a Linear to design a song list screen, inside of Linear Layout in bottom there is a Relative Layout that should be in look like in image attachment, any suggestion how I can round bottom of a Relative Layout and how I can use Gradient colours in it as it is shown in image attached with this post?

[image]

Comment: Why not just put an image as the background with curved bottom

Comment: @ blessenm was good if I am using same size screens,but it creates problems when the size of screen changes for different devices .thanks . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use relative layout and for relative layout use background image as rounded..

```
<RelatvieLayout>
 android:id="@+id/relative"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@drawable/curvebackground"
 android:alignparent_bottom="true">

 <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imageview"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="" // here source of the imageview
  android:align_parentLeft="true"/>
 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/textview"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:align_centerInParent="true"/>
 <Button
  android:id="@+id/button"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:align_parentRight="true"
 />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit:

In relative layout add these lines so that it correctly fetches to the corresponding width of the screen.

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

Comment: you are right.but what happening when I add component component like EditText,Button etc comes outside from that background.

Comment: wat comes outside?? ie background is not for full width?? if so try to add some line in relative layout..check my answer..

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the LinearLayout by override the onDraw method refer to this article for more details

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Comment: thanks for suggestion . Rajdeep Dua please will you more detail on it how I can Draw my custom Linear Layout using onDraw method  ?As am new and I never do like this before,thanks again

Answer (score 0):

just use a curved background - modifying a layout's onDraw seems too overkill for your problem.
for using curved background on a relative size screen, you may need to read on [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html)